# javascriptでの配列ソートについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript(jquery)で配列の中を以下のような順番でソートしたいです。
A1-1
A1-3
A1-3-1
A1-4
A2
A4-1
A6-3
A13-1
A13-2
A13-3
A13-11
A13-14
A51-2
しかし文字列の比較を用いてソートすると以下のようになってしまいます。
A1-1
A1-3
A1-3-1
A1-4
A13-1
A13-11
A13-14
A13-2
A13-3
A2
A4-1
A51-2
A6-3
最初のような形でソートするにはハイフンで文字列を区切ってそれぞれを数値に変換して比較するしかないのでしょうか。
現在のソートの処理は以下の通りです。

```
sortedAlphabetListData.sort(
  function(a,b){
    if( a[0] < b[0] ) return -1;
    if( a[0] > b[0] ) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
);
```

コメントいただいた中で、自然順アルゴリズムというものが実現したいものに近いことがわかりました。
https://gist.github.com/think49/660141
こちらのサイトのライブラリを使ってみたのですが、A23,A3-1という順番で表示されてしまいます。A3-1が先に来てほしいです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings
ここのサイトを参考に、以下のようにコードを修正しました。ただし、この方法はIE11以上でないと動かない　ですしSafariでは動かないので使えません。（今回はIE9以上をサポートする必要があります。）

```
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
var sortedAlphabetListData = alphabetListData.sort(collator.compare);
```

このようにしたところ、以下のようにA1-3-1とA1-3が逆になります。
A1-1
A1-3-1
A1-3

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 今回の要件は要は「自然順アルゴリズム」でのソートでよろしいですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so そうです！その言葉は聞いたことが無かったのですが、それで検索するとnatsort.jsというライブラリが見つかり、それを使用すれば実現できそうです！ありがとうございました！

Comment: @keitaro_so natsort.jsを使用してみたのですが、実現できませんでした。
https://gist.github.com/think49/660141
先ほどの例の内容でしたら正しくソートできたのですが、例えば
A23,A3-1
でしたら先にA3-1が来てほしいのですが、そうなりません。

Comment: 回答者は質問者さんの希望に応えるのではなく、書かれている質問文に答えることしかできません。１つ１つ後出しせず、どのような結果になって欲しいかを明確にした上で質問文を更新してください。

Comment: @sayuri 
おっしゃる通りです。私としては後出しというつもりはなく、最初に載せたパターンが直れば全部が直ると思っていたのですが、実際には直るところを直らないところがあった、ということです。申し訳ありません。より具体的に書きましたので、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @FESHIMO 前者と後者で配列の内容が変わってしまっているのでソートの内容も変わるのではないでしょうか？まずは前者のソートアルゴリズムが出来たと言うことで一旦区切り、そこからこのソート順にしたいと別の質問にした方がいいのでは？後者の値も2桁のフォーマットが無いようですし前者と一致せずサンプルとして不適切な気がします。

Comment: @Myaku 
前者のアルゴリズムで実現できたのはIE11以上でないと動かず、今回はIE9以上をサポートしなければならないので、前者の方法でも解決は出来ていません。全体的にわかりにくくなってしまったので、整理して書き直しました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問に書かれていますが、「ハイフンで切って、それぞれを数値に変換して比較する」という地道な方法をとるべきだと思います。13という文字と3という文字を比較して、13のほうが大きいと判断するには数値に変換する他に方法がありませんから。

Comment: ソートする文字列の１文字目は全てAですか？それともB3-13-43のように他の文字もあり得ますか？Aと数字以外で使われる文字は"-"だけですか？　"--"という文字列を含む事はありますか？　どのようなデータを処理しなければならないかを明確にしてください（現れうるすべてのパターンを示してください）。

Comment: 今度は動作させるブラウザーの追加ですか？ 必要となるブラウザーをきちんと列挙してください。他にも条件がないか見直してください。

Comment: （仕様が不明瞭なので現状での指摘ですが）先頭のアルファベットを削ればハイフンが区切り文字のversion stringのソートになるのではないでしょうか。これなら既存のライブラリなどが活用できますね。区切って比較するのと本質的には等価ですが…

Comment: @Fumu7 
コメントありがとうございました。英語版の方で回答が得られましたので、自分で回答を転載しました。ご協力いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @sayuri 
コメントありがとうございました。英語版の方で回答が得られましたので、自分で回答を転載しました。何度もご指摘いただき、申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: @rio.irikami 
コメントありがとうございました。英語版の方で回答が得られましたので、自分で回答を転載しました。ご協力いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://gist.github.com/think49/660141
>   こちらのサイトのライブラリを使ってみたのですが、A23,A3-1という順番で表示されてしまいます。A3-1が先に来てほしいです。

配布元の作者です。
現象を再現できた為、natsort-1.2.4.js で修正しました。

- [natsort.js : 自然順アルゴリズムで配列をソート](https://gist.github.com/think49/660141)

要件は満たしていると思います。

```
natsort(["A13-1","A13-3","A13-14","A4-1","A13-11","A1-1","A13-2","A51-2","A2","A1-3","A6-3","A1-3-1","A1-4"]); // ["A1-1","A1-3","A1-3-1","A1-4","A2","A4-1","A6-3","A13-1","A13-2","A13-3","A13-11","A13-14","A51-2"]
```

[Natural Order String Comparison](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/)のサンプルでも要件を満たします。

```
natsort(['a','a2','a1a','a1b','a10','a0','a20','a1']);  // ["a","a0","a1","a1a","a1b","a2","a10","a20"]
natsort(['1.02','1.002','1.3','1.001','1.1','1.010']);  // ["1.001","1.002","1.010","1.02","1.1","1.3"]
natsort(['x2-g8','x2-y7','x8-y8','x2-y08']);            // ["x2-g8", "x2-y7", "x2-y08", "x8-y8"]
natsort(['1.02','1.002','1.3','1.001','1.1','1.010']);  // ["1.001", "1.002", "1.010", "1.02", "1.1", "1.3"]
```

Re: FESHIMO さん

Comment: わざわざ配布者の方が対応してくださるとは思いませんでした。ありがとうございます！今回は先の回答の通りの処理で納品してしまったのですが、今後同様の仕様があった場合には利用させていただきます！

Answer (score 1):

自然順アルゴリズムで処理できるライブラリがあるようでした
https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-natural-sort

例えば node.js で利用する場合

```
npm install javascript-natural-sort
```

のようにインストールを行い、`natsort_sample.js` というファイル名で内容を

```
const naturalSort = require("javascript-natural-sort");
console.log(["A1-1",
"A1-3",
"A1-3-1",
"A1-4",
"A13-1",
"A13-11",
"A13-14",
"A13-2",
"A13-3",
"A2",
"A4-1",
"A51-2",
"A6-3",
].sort(naturalSort))
```

のように保存して実行すると以下のような結果になりました

```
node natsort_sample.js
[ 'A1-1',
  'A1-3',
  'A1-3-1',
  'A1-4',
  'A2',
  'A4-1',
  'A6-3',
  'A13-1',
  'A13-2',
  'A13-3',
  'A13-11',
  'A13-14',
  'A51-2' ]
```

Comment: ライブラリを調べていただきありがとうございました。これは私も調査している中で見つけていたのですが、私が動作させたいのはブラウザのフロントで動くjavascriptで、このライブラリは使えないと判断しました。情報が不足しており大変申し訳ありません。お手数をおかけしました。

Comment: なるほどです。少しみた限り上記の node_module ですが元々は Github の https://github.com/tablesort/javascript-natural-sort を fork したもののようなのでこちらであれば特に手を加えずにブラウザで動くような感じでした

https://github.com/tablesort/javascript-natural-sort/blob/396f7743a1103ab7988f41a2d4d6aeaf252de7fd/index.html

で html で動かしてるサンプルがあるようです
参考になればと思います

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。見たところこれはサンプルではなくて紹介ページのようですね？今回はとりあえずライブラリを使わずに自前でfunctionを作る方法が見つかったので、それを使うことにしました。ご協力いただき本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントをして下さった皆様、ありがとうございました。また、私の説明が不足しているせいで皆様に御迷惑をお掛けして申し訳ありませんでした。
[英語版の方にも同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051217/4698341)をして、回答を得られましたので今後のために載せておきます。
回答は2個あり、どちらでも今回の要望を実現出来ました。
ご協力いただきありがとうございました。

[一つ目](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479354/4698341) (by [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg))

```
function naturalCompare(a, b) {
    var ax = [], bx = [];
    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });

    while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }
    return ax.length - bx.length;
}
test.sort(naturalCompare)
```

[二つ目](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051217/4698341) (by [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz))

```
function customSort(data, order) {

    function isNumber(v) {
        return (+v).toString() === v;
    }

    var sort = {
            asc: function (a, b) {
                var i = 0,
                    l = Math.min(a.value.length, b.value.length);

                while (i < l && a.value[i] === b.value[i]) {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i === l) {
                    return a.value.length - b.value.length;
                }
                if (isNumber(a.value[i]) && isNumber(b.value[i])) {
                    return a.value[i] - b.value[i];
                }
                return a.value[i].localeCompare(b.value[i]);
            },
            desc: function (a, b) {
                return sort.asc(b, a);
            }
        },
        mapped = data.map(function (el, i) {
            var string = el.replace(/\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\.)/gi, '$&. .'),
                regex = /(\d+)|([^0-9.]+)/g,
                m,
                parts = [];

            while ((m = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
                parts.push(m[0]);
            }
            return { index: i, value: parts, o: el, string: string };
        });

    mapped.sort(sort[order] || sort.asc);
    return mapped.map(function (el) {
        return data[el.index];
    });
}

var array = ['A1-1', 'A1-3', 'A1-3-1', 'A1-4', 'A2', 'A4-1', 'A6-3', 'A13-1', 'A13-2', 'A13-3', 'A13-11', 'A13-14', 'A51-2'];

console.log(customSort(array));
console.log(customSort(array, 'desc'));
```

Comment: stackoverflowのライセンスであるCC-BY-SA 3.0に基づき引用元の回答と回答の投稿者へのリンクを追加させて頂きました。

Comment: @hinaloe
回答の編集、ありがとうございました！今後回答を引用する際にはリンクを貼るようにします。